# Get a value from a reference to a hash

Tags: perl, hash

I know that there have been multiple posts about this topic already, but I have not found them to be helpful for my particular case.

When I run this excerpt of code

```
my $bandName = ''; 

my $rrh_sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT serial....");
$rrh_sth->execute;

my $int_hash = $rrh_sth->fetchall_hashref('serial');
delete $_->{serial} for values %$int_hash;

foreach my $s ( keys %$int_hash ) {

    if ( $values[6] eq $s ) {

        #$bandName =  @{%$int_hash}{$s};
        $bandName = $int_hash ->{$s};

        my $ulink = getFreq($bandName, "u");
        my $dlink = getFreq($bandName, "d");

        my $status = "active";

        print Dumper (
            $bandName,
            $values[0],
            $values[8],
            $values[7],
            $values[6],
            $values[11],
            $values[10],
            $values[3],
            $values[4],
            $values[5],
            $dlink,
            $ulink
        );
    }   
}
```

I keep getting the key and the value for the particular serial, represented by `$s`. I know that I have to de-reference `int_hash`, but I am not sure how now that the methods that I have tried do not work.

```
$VAR1 = {
    'rrhName' => 'MCD59'
};
$VAR2 = 'MCO57';
$VAR3 = 'R-S-S:1-0-1';
$VAR4 = 'scb';
$VAR5 = '12NT46000050';
$VAR6 = undef;
$VAR7 = '109786038';
$VAR8 = 'MCO: 976 2x5W AC';
$VAR9 = 'enabled';
$VAR10 = '1';
$VAR11 = ''; #EDITED
$VAR12 = ''; #EDITED
```

In general, when I have a reference, I need to dereference it to get to the slices, but in the case of `$VAR1`, when I go to my database to see the value being inserted its telling me the position of `$VAR1` in memory, which is not what I thought I was asking for.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the problem -- you dereference correctly, and `getFreq` seems to correctly fetch data.  As for the first one, `$int_hash->{$s}{'rrhName'}` will give you `MCD59`. (You may also leave out the single quotes, so `{rrhName}`.) Is this what you need?

Comment: @zdim I just want 'MCD59' not the rest of that for $VAR1. In my database table, what you see above for $VAR1 turns to 'HASH(0x325e94)' and not 'MCD59'. Also, that was my mistake, getFreq returns blanks. so $VAR11 and $VAR12 are '' each.

Comment: Alright, I'll post what I think you need. Let me know then.  Btw, I edited the question to remove the extra code indentation. If you don't like it that way please just roll it back.

Comment: But that did work, I think it was just a goofy error, I thought that $s was the $rrhName. Could you explain the line you posted in your first post. I dont quite understand it.

Comment: If you have remaining uncertainty about dealing with references in Perl, I highly recommend [Mark's very short tutorial about references](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) which is part of the standard documentation that ships with Perl. Set aside 20min to read it  - your life will be improved :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `$int_hash` is a hash reference, and you dereference it correctly into a hash, `%$int_hash`,  to then retrieve its keys. The obtained key is then also used correctly to get the corresponding value, `$int_hash->{$s}`.

However, as the `Dumper` output shows, the value associated with the key `$s` is itself a hash reference. Since a reference itself is a scalar we can always assign it as a value to a key, which is how complex (nested) data structures are built.  See [`perldsc`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html) for a cookbook and for references in general see [`perlreftut`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) for a tutorial and [`perlref`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html) for a reference.

In short, you only need to keep dereferencing

```
$int_hash->{$s}->{'rrhName'};  # or,
$int_hash->{$s}{'rrhName'};    # or even
$int_hash->{$s}{rrhName};
```

The second and third lines are syntax shortcuts, explained in the above pages.

Either of these will return the value in the nested hash, `MCD59`.

Comment: But how is the value itself a hash reference. I thought one you dereference the hash, you can obtain the values.

Comment: @noc_coder  Thank you for the attribution.  I've added a statement from my comment (removed it now for a typo in it) and some links.  Please let me know if more would be better.

Comment: I understand it now. Very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

You are committing the sin of doing a linear search for a key in the hash `%$int_hash` that matches `$values[6]`. You don't access arrays that way. It would look like this

```
my $values_6;

for my $i ( 0 .. $#values ) {
    if ( $i == 6 ) {
        $values_6 = $values[$i];
    }
}
```

You need to discard your `for` loop and simply access the hash element directly. Combining that with accessing the value of the second-level hash, your code should look like this

```
my $band_name;

if ( my $band = $int_hash->{$values[6]} ) {

        $band_name = $band->{rrhName};

        my $ulink  = getFreq($band_name, 'u');
        my $dlink  = getFreq($band_name, 'd');
        my $status = 'active';
}
```

Comment: I remember you helping me before with Perl questions lol. The array values and the %int_hash are two separate data structures. Apologies that this wasnt clear in the excerpt. I am looping over each serial in the hash for each serial in @values(pulled from a different query) to find a match. @values isnt the values from the hash.